# Convert ctype byte array to bytes

Tags: python-2.7, ctypes

I have a ctypes array that I defined like this:

```
buff= (c_ubyte*buff_size)()
```

After filling the buffer up with data, I need to have this data in bytes format. Right now I'm doing it as follows:

```
buff= [n for n in buff]
buff = ''.join(map(chr, buff))
```

The problem with this is that it converts it to a 4-byte (or whatever number of bytes) int before converting it back into a single byte string, which wastes a lot of CPU.

How can I convert the ctypes buffer into bytes directly? I'm not trying to save myself a copy because I do have to do a copy anyway since I cannot keep the original buffer. Does python have a cast feature for such things?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you getting data into the "buff" originally"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you did want a copy, you could use `bytearray`:

```
>>> buff = (c_ubyte * 4)(*[97,98,99,100])
>>> bs = bytearray(buff)
>>> bs
bytearray(b'abcd')
>>> str(bs)
'abcd'
```

> **Edit**:
>
> For Python versions prior to 2.6 that lack `bytearray`, you can
>   use one of the following instead:
>
> - `cast(buff, c_char_p).value`
> - `buffer(buff)[:]`

If you want to share the same buffer, you can create a `c_char` array:

```
>>> buff2 = (c_char * len(buff)).from_buffer(buff)
>>> buff2.value # string copy
'abcd'
>>> buff2[:] = 'efgh'
>>> buff[:]  # modified original
[101, 102, 103, 104]
```

> **Edit**:
>
> The `from_buffer` class method was added in 2.6. In prior versions you
>   can use `cast`:
>
> - `buff2 = cast(buff, POINTER(c_char * len(buff)))[0]`

Is there a reason you aren't using a `c_char` array to begin with? I understand if you need to work with it as both a numeric array and as a string.

Addendum:

The 2nd method is more 'cast' like since it doesn't copy the buffer. With the first approach it gets copied twice, once to make the `bytearray` and again to make the `str` (`bytes` is an alias for `str` in 2.x). But a `bytearray` has string methods and may be all you need; it's basically a mutable version of 3.x `bytes`.

`c_char` is the C `char` type. Multiplied to an array, it's a mutable buffer of bytes like your current `c_ubyte` array. However, it may be more convenient than `c_ubyte` since it has the `value` and `raw` descriptors that return Python byte strings. It also indexes and iterates as single character byte strings instead of integers.

What you're not supposed to do is create a `c_char_p` -- a pointer to character data -- from a Python string if the function will modify the it. Python strings objects are immutable; you can get weird bugs if you modify their buffer. I recently [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15381220/205580) on that topic.

Comment: The first solution worked, but I had to use bytes(bytearray(buff)), since neither one alone worked. The reason I'm not using c_char; for one I'd still need to convert to bytes, second, I thought c_char is supposed to be un-mutable, so I wouldn't be able to modify the buffer in my dll. Although from the ctypes docs it wasn't clear to me what is considered mutable here.

Comment: Where is it mentioned that bytes() and bytearray() copies the objects? Because I'm still having trouble with the second method. Using '((ctypes.c_char * len(buff)).from_buffer(buff)).raw' I get '"TypeError: expected a writeable buffer object"' and using '.value' instead cuts the buffer off, probably at the first \00.

Comment: I had to do from_buffer_copy, otherwise it crashed. Thanks!

Comment: `value` will cut off at null. It's useful when a library writes a null-terminated string into the buffer. How was `buff` created such that it's read-only? That exception is raised by `PyObject_AsWriteBuffer` if it's not a buffer (e.g. `(c_char * 4).from_buffer([1,2,3,4])`) or if the buffer is read-only or can't say how many segments it has (should be only 1 segment).

Comment: As to `bytearray`, I just read the source. [`bytearray_init`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Objects/bytearrayobject.c#l846) (CPython 2.7.3) creates a view of the buffer, resizes itself, and calls `PyBuffer_ToContiguous` to copy the data.

Comment: The error arose (I think) when the original data was created using (c_ubyte*len(buff))() and then I called on it (ctypes.c_char*len(buff)).from_buffer(buff).raw. I assumed that I didn't need to create the original buffer with c_char type as well, but I guess I did.

Comment: @Matt: I thought `buff` was your `c_ubyte` array. In that case I don't understand the goal of `(c_ubyte*len(buff))()`, which creates a 2nd `c_ubyte` array. When the `from_buffer` call fails, what type does `print type(buff)`show? `buff` has to be a writable buffer such as a `c_ubyte_Array_[N]`.

Comment: When I try the `buff2 = (c_char * len(buff)).from_buffer(buff)` variant I get `AttributeError: type object 'c_char_Array_6' has no attribute 'from_buffer'`.  (In this case, len(buff)==6, obviously.)

Comment: well shoot, that's the second time today using a version pre 2.6 has bitten me... what do i do for that case?

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading the question up top, but I interpreted `buff= (c_ubyte*buff_size)()` to mean that `buff` is a c_ubyte array, which needs to be converted *to* a Python string (which your answer, through the `value` field, did produce).

Comment: get an existing c_ubyte array as a Python string in 2.5

Comment: @michael, FYI, `memoryview` replaces `buffer` in PY3, so the equivalent conversion is `memoryview(buff).tobytes()`, but more simply it's just `bytes(buff)`.

Comment: @eryksun sorry, what?  'bytes' isn't defined, are you talking about 2.5 or 3?

Comment: seems like `''.join([chr(n) for n in buff])` is the best I can do.

Comment: @Michael, `memoryview` replaces `buffer` in 3.x, and the new byte string type is `bytes`. The `bytes` type can initialize using the buffer interface (not the same as the 2.x `buffer` *type*), allowing one to use `bytes(buff)` in 3.x, the same way one can use `bytearray(buff)` in 2.6+.

Comment: @Michael, I don't understand how joining a list comp is the best you can do. Even using `map` is better than that. The alternatives for 2.5 that I added, using `cast` or `buffer`, are more efficient than using `''.join(map(chr, buff))`.