# Passing Char Array With Unknown Encoding

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, ctypes

Let's say I have `char content[500]` in C++, and it contains some characters in unknown encoding, and I would like to pass it to a python 3 code via ctypes callback.

Here is a demo code I created:

```
typedef int (*callback)(char *);

extern "C" {
  void foo(callback cb);
}

void foo(callback cb) {
  char hello_world[] = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0','w','o','r','l','d'};
  cb(hello_world);
}
```

The Python 3 code:

```
from ctypes import *

callback = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_char*11)

def py_callback(b):
    with open('/tmp/test', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(b)
    return 0

cb = cdll.LoadLibrary("/tmp/callback.so")
cb.foo(callback(py_callback))
```

I thought I would see 'hello\0world' in `/tmp/test` but I see following instead:

```
# hexdump -C /tmp/test 
00000000  50 5e 46 27 fc 7f 00 00  00 00 00                 |P^F'.......|
0000000b
```

If I declare callback as `callback = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_char_p)`, then it can't handle the null terminated character in between.

And even if there is no null terminated character in between, I need to call `f.write(b.decode('utf8'))` to get it work but then it means I need to know the encoding in advance, which I don't.  Hence, I would like just write whatever bytes in the array to the file.

Suggestion?

Comment: a bit offtopic, but why arent you using `char hello_world[] = "hello\0world";`. And you know `\0` is a string terminator, right? And why are you including `<string>`?

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15382322)

Comment: @JHBonarius yes I know `\0` is a string terminator.  I on purpose used it in my example above to demonstrate that I want to write the full array into a file rather than write just the string (which will be just `hello`) into the file.  Let me drop the useless `#include`, I was playing around with the code and forgot to remove it.

Comment: @JHBonarius I looked at your link, and I tried to change `c_char*11` to `c_ubyte*11` and then `f.write(b)` to `f.write(str(bytearray(b)))` but it gives `bytearray(b'\xc0c\xf6\xef\xfc\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')` in `/tmp/test` and the 5 `\0` at the end doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`c_char_p` has special handling to expect null-termination and convert to a Python `str`.  Use `POINTER(c_char)` instead to suppress the automatic handling, but you need to know the size of the returned data if it isn't null-terminated.  With `POINTER(c_char)`, you can convert the returned `ctypes.LP_c_char` to a Python string using string slicing of the correct size:

**test.cpp**

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

typedef void (*CALLBACK)(char *, size_t);

extern "C"
{

API void foo(CALLBACK cb) {
    char hello_world[] = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0','w','o','r','l','d'};
    if(cb)
        cb(hello_world, sizeof hello_world);
}

}
```

**test.py**

```
from ctypes import *

CALLBACK = CFUNCTYPE(None, POINTER(c_char), c_size_t)

@CALLBACK
def py_callback(data,size):
    with open('out.bin', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(data[:size])

dll = CDLL('./test')
dll.foo.argtypes = CALLBACK,
dll.foo.restype = None

dll.foo(py_callback)
```

`out.bin` hex dump:

[image: hexadecimal dump of out.bin]